# using ruby, how to index a postgres database with elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, elasticsearch, sinatra

I am using sinatra and postgres. I want to index a postgres database.

The ruby code is:

```
get '/elastic_data' do
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
candidates.select(:id, :first, :last, :email, :industry).map do |row|
@first = row[:first]
puts @first
@industry = row[:industry]
puts @industry
result = {first:@first, industry:@industry}.to_json
client.index  index: 'people', type: 'py', id: 1, body: result
end
end
```

When I run this, in the terminal I get what appears to be nicely formed json as follows:

```
Eric
Legal
2014-06-11 18:05:00 +0100: PUT http://localhost:9200/people/py/1 [status:200, request:0.004s, query:n/a]
2014-06-11 18:05:00 +0100: > {"first":"Eric","industry":"Legal"}
2014-06-11 18:05:00 +0100: < {"ok":true,"_index":"people","_type":"py","_id":"1","_version":10143}
Kewu
Legal
2014-06-11 18:05:00 +0100: PUT http://localhost:9200/people/py/1 [status:200, request:0.002s, query:n/a]
2014-06-11 18:05:00 +0100: > {"first":"Kewu","industry":"Legal"}
2014-06-11 18:05:00 +0100: < {"ok":true,"_index":"people","_type":"py","_id":"1","_version":10144}
```

and then I get an error message which is this:

```
NoMethodError at /elastic_data
undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash:0x9228f40>
```

2 questions:

1. What's going wrong and how can I fix it?
2. Is there an "update"  command with the elasticsearch ruby gem so that I can update the index each time there is a new record or do I have to re-index the database each time I do a  search?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is *highly* unorthodox - trying to sync two different repositories with the same data is brittle, error-prone and a recipe for a major headache.

From the kind of data that is shown in your snippets, I don't even see the use-case, why not simply [add an index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html) to your postgres table? Postgres even supports [full text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch.html), so that even if you had real temptation to use elasticsearch for that (after all - this is one of its main features), for most use-cases postgres will do.

In the remote case where you absolutely *need* features from elasticsearch which postgres does not provide, I would suggest porting this table to elasticsearch *completely* rather than trying to keep the two repositories in sync...

Comment: Fair enough and thank you for the observation. However the Sequel ORM, which I am using, while it supports "full_text_search" only operates with one word not a phrase for the query element. This is limiting so I decided (mistakenly it would seem) to experiment with elasticsearch. Another approach that I have considered is to upload a csv file and then index that. The question would probably then be the same, how do I generate a proper json document that will not return an error. Do you have a view on that? Thanks for your time.

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean by "stack trace". Would you like the whole bit from the terminal, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, the whole error message, with the list of sources where the error occurred